# Unity3D - Game running very slow in Editor but very good in Build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2017.2.
I have strange problem. When i run my game into the editor it drops the FPS to very low like 5 - 7 FPS. However if i make a build and run the game it runs perfectly without any problems with 150 - 200 FPS.

Here is my profiler:

[image]

All is runing fine without any errors. Can you give me any suggestion where the problem can be. I hope somebody faced similar problem before and i'll be able to resolve this.

Comment: Is it possible that the Unity3D program is configured to use your integrated graphics card while a build of the game uses your dedicated gpu?

Comment: Do i set this up somewhere from configurations of Unity or ? i haven't any specific configurations about that. And also when i run the build i do not see any notification about switching the graphics cards like it does when i launch other games. This was the first thing that i have checked. I'm pretty sure the build is also running with the integrated graphics card but there seems to not have any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-text-high-cpu-usage-2017-2-0f3.499931/) unity forum post, it seems this is a known issue with the editor itself. You can either roll back to the last version, or wait for a bugfix to come out... Although the fix for this has been "expected soon" for awhile now. It is possible that 2017.3 fixed this issue, though. I haven't updated Unity since it came out so I cannot confirm.

Comment: It's fixed in 2017.2